# Nine year old HP PC fails to boot with no error beeps

Tags: memory, display, cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure

When I turn on my PC, the screen said "no signal".
I checked the RAM  with no error beep, even without RAM, but when I remove the CPU it beeps.
So i really need to check if the motherboard still alive or not and detect exactly where is the issue.
All the fans are running.
i did try two different GPUs to make sure of it.
Specs:
[HP Z400 Xeon w3565](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01709672)  ([parts list](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01716997?jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001))
RAM 6 GB
Quadro 2000
It gives me a black screen.

Comment: Please remove and reseat the CPU and the memory, making sure everything is well connected. Also, disconnect every peripheral power and data cable, and try just to reach BIOS/Setup after power-on. Once you have done that, click [edit] and add at the bottom of your post what your result is.

Comment: I did what you said but still giving me a black screen

Comment: When you respond, please click [edit] and add at the bottom of your post what your result is, so everyone can see all details of a problem in the question.

Comment: Try https://www.lifewire.com/fix-computer-that-turns-on-but-displays-nothing-2624443 https://www.business2community.com/tech-gadgets/5-ways-to-fix-a-computer-with-a-black-screen-0518305 However, that box is worth maybe $200. The CPU and RAM are not usable in modern PCs. the video card is antique, and since HP may not have standardized the chassis it's in, replacing the motherboard probably won't work because it probably won't take the standard ATX form factor motherboard.

Comment: Do you think i have a bad motherboard or a bad cpu or a bad RAM slots

Comment: No way to tell without swapping parts. Finding those for a nine year old PC is unlikely.

Comment: Tnx for your help

Comment: Take it to a shop / pc repair center

Answer (score 0):

As addition to the above comments.

Through your description of the symptoms, it might be some misconfiguration in the BIOS, or an empty BIOS-Battery ?!

First, open the Case.

To reset the BIOS :

> Switch off the PC and pull out the power cable
>
> Push the Reset-Button (small yellow Button) diagonal to the Battery, for few seconds(3,5 or 10). (As in the 
>   Picture below)
>
> Push back the Power Cable and switch on your PC. Does it boot as expected ?

If a Bios Reset doesn't work, try this, 
To change the Battery :

> Just switch off the PC and pull out the current cable.
>
> Change the Battery with a full charged new BIOS-Battery.
>
> Push the power cable again in, and switch on the PC.

[image: Picture with the small Battery to change]

Comment: i have already changed the battery with new one and did what you said but the screen still black

Answer (score 0):

The screen works on other PCs?
Nvidia Quadro 2000's sometimes die.
You could replace the graphics card with a used card of the same type from ebay.